# How to put a line in the middle of two tables

Tags: html, css

How can I make the same as this?

[image]

At the moment,my page looks like this:

[image]

Here my snippet pen:http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/ALPgbG

Am trying to use border but it is not really working as you can see from the picture.

```
table.table-1 {
    border-right: 1px solid #eeb422;
}
```

Hope you can help.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: give margin-right to class table.table-1

Comment: @chirag. IO just updated the images so you can see better how  the line looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go buddy. Check out my [codepen link](http://codepen.io/Aalind/pen/qarrXP).

You basically need to `give some padding to the parent div` with class `tables`. And then give `border-left to the right table` along with `sufficient padding` as per your requirements. Hope this is helpful ! :)

**EDIT 1 :-** 
If you want to remove extra space from the heading which is showing ( as someone pointed out in the comments ), you simply need to give `margin as 0px` to the `class orange` ( basically the `h3 tag which has some default margin` which needs to be removed ). Please check the following [codepen link](http://codepen.io/Aalind/pen/ALPPxp) for that solution.

```css
section#products{
  background-color: green;
}
li{
  list-style: none;
}
ul{
  padding-left:0;
}

span.cigars {
    color: white;
}

section#products div.container > p {
    margin-bottom: 3px;
}

tr {
    text-align: left;
}

table{
    width: 50%;
}

th.tg-yw4l,
td.tg-yw4l,
.tables {
    display: flex;
}

.tables{
    padding: 30px;
}

table ul:nth-child(odd) {
  /*  padding-right: 60px;*/
}

table.table-2 {
    border-left: 1px solid #eeb422;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<section id="products">
  <div class="tables">
    <table class="table-1">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
          <h3 class="orange">Cuban <span class="cigars">Cigars</span></h3>
          </td>
          </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="tg-yw4l">
            <ul class="list-1">
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="list-2">
              <li></li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
            </ul>
          </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          <h3 class="orange">Machine made <span class="cigars">Cigars</span></h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="tg-yw4l">
            <ul class="list-1">
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="list-2">
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="table-2">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <h3 class="orange">Non Cuban <span class="cigars">Cigars</span></h3>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th class="tg-yw4l">
            <ul class="list-1">
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="list-2">
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
              <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
            </ul>
          </th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>
        <h3 class="orange">Other</h3>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="tg-yw4l">
        <ul class="list-1">
          <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
          <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
          <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
          <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
          <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
          <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
          <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
          <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
          <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
          <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="list-2">
          <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
          <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
          <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
          <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
          <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
          <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
          <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
          <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
          <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
          <li>Lorem Ipsum is simply</li>
        </ul>
        </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: .It still looks nearly the same as the one he did. If you check the line and compare the photos on the question posted you'll see that the line cannot go far to the the top as it is now.

Comment: @Aalind Sharma.I was actually focusing more  the line in the middle.Can it not be shorter at top as the first photo on my question shows?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @WosleyAlarico check out my edit ( EDIT 1 ). Does it solve your issue now ?

Comment: Well it looks like I had forgotten about  the margin on the h3 yes. Problem solved and answer voted.